# Unable to get the Property defined in custom UI dialog in WiX Installer

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I am using a custom UI dialog for my WiX installer. In the custom dialog, I am having an Edit Text like :

```
<Control Id="NameEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="85" Width="220" Height="18" Property="MyVal" Text="{80}" />
```

Now when I am using this property to set the registry, it is giving me null value.

```
<RegistryValue Type="string" Name="VPIP" Value="[MyVal]"/>
```

I have tried with other property, there it is working fine, but when I use the property from custom dialog file, it is setting null.

Can someone point out, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property names in the UI need to be uppercase (so that they are public) and marked secure='yes' in their declaration for them to transfer to the execution stage in the service.